# Dhall Record to Text

Tags: dhall

I'm looking for the Dhall equivalent of Java's `toString` so I can embed some raw JSON inside another record, but I wish to ensure the resulting JSON structure is valid.

I have a Record, e.g. `{ name : Text, age : Natural }` and wish to convert a value to Text, e.g.:

```
let friends = 
[ { name = "Bob", age = 25 }, { name = "Alice", age = 24 }]
in { id = "MyFriends", data = Record/toString friends }
```

which would produce:

```
{
  "id": "MyFriends, 
  "data": "[ { \"name\": \"Bob\", \"age\": 25 }, { \"name\": \"Alice\", \"age\": 24 }]" 
}
```

Is this possible in Dhall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformation to JSON can't be derived automatically, but you can use the Prelude's support for JSON to generate correct-by-construction JSON strings (meaning that they will never be malformed), like this:

```
let Prelude = https://prelude.dhall-lang.org/v13.0.0/package.dhall

let Friend = { name : Text, age : Natural }

let Friend/ToJSON
    : Friend → Prelude.JSON.Type
    =   λ(friend : Friend)
      → Prelude.JSON.object
          ( toMap
              { name = Prelude.JSON.string friend.name
              , age = Prelude.JSON.natural friend.age
              }
          )

let Friends/ToJSON
    : List Friend → Prelude.JSON.Type
    =   λ(friends : List Friend)
      → Prelude.JSON.array
          (Prelude.List.map Friend Prelude.JSON.Type Friend/ToJSON friends)

let friends = [ { name = "Bob", age = 25 }, { name = "Alice", age = 24 } ]

in  { id = "MyFriends", data = Prelude.JSON.render (Friends/ToJSON friends) }
```

That produces the following result:

```
{ data =
    "[ { \"age\": 25, \"name\": \"Bob\" }, { \"age\": 24, \"name\": \"Alice\" } ]"
, id = "MyFriends"
}
```